# Learning Redshift EXPLAIN plan

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need some help in understanding the following Explain plan please:

1. I have following query that returns 219 records and takes around 40 seconds to run:

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    (TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('second', CONVERT_TIMEZONE('GMT', 'UTC', "ABC"."time")), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) AS "rtime",
    COUNT(DISTINCT ABC.s) AS "s"
FROM
    ABC
    INNER JOIN TE ON "ABC"."e_id" = "TE"."e_id"
WHERE "TE"."e_code" = 'ABCDE'
GROUP by 1 
ORDER BY 1
```

**Explain plan:**

```
XN Merge  (cost=1000000944628.86..1000000944629.36 rows=200 width=200)
  Merge Key: resp
  ->  XN Network  (cost=1000000944628.86..1000000944629.36 rows=200 width=200)
        Send to leader
        ->  XN Sort  (cost=1000000944628.86..1000000944629.36 rows=200 width=200)
              Sort Key: resp
              ->  XN HashAggregate  (cost=944620.71..944621.21 rows=200 width=200)
                    ->  XN Subquery Scan volt_dt_0  (cost=944506.75..944606.47 rows=2849 width=200)
                          ->  XN HashAggregate  (cost=944506.75..944577.98 rows=2849 width=29)
                                ->  XN Hash Join DS_DIST_ALL_NONE  (cost=132.60..944492.51 rows=2849 width=29)
                                      Hash Cond: (((("outer".context_id)::text || ':'::text) || ("outer".e_id)::text) = ("inner".e_id)::text)
                                      ->  XN Seq Scan on ABC (cost=0.00..151081.63 rows=15108163 width=33)
                                      ->  XN Hash  (cost=132.60..132.60 rows=2 width=17)
                                            ->  XN Seq Scan on te  (cost=0.00..132.60 rows=2 width=17)
                                                  Filter: ((e_code)::text = 'ABCDE'::text)
```

**Following is the ABC table and TE table setup details:**

```
DISTSTYLE EVEN
SORTKEY ( inserted_datetime );
```

```
DISTSTYLE ALL
SORTKEY ( e_id );
```

I wanted to speed this query up and I had following questions please:

> 1. Is Order clause problem here or is it Sequence Scan? **I believe it is Sequence Scan but I am not sure what I can to fix it?**
> 2. Can I say higher value for cost implies, it will take more time? **I think, it is not.**
> 3. Why is does 'XN Hash Join DS_DIST_ALL_NONE' in place of 'EVEN' DISTSTYLE? **Is it because both tables has different DISTSTYLE?**
> 4. Why is it using Subquery Scan here? **No idea**

Kindly guide me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The sub-query that generates the volt_dt intermediate results is a big clue.  Redshift will break up queries with complex / large data size plans this way to keep things bounded.  Another clue is your use of DISTINCT.  Here’s what I think is going on (but there is some additional data that will be needed to be sure).

Your JOIN is creating a very large in dataset (in the billions of rows) due to too many matches on the ON clause. This large data set needs to be redistributed around the Redshift for aggregation.   So you need to make the large data set and then redistribute it which is what is taking all the time.  The aggregation is on a generated value which adds addition work.  I suspect this is where the time is going.

This type of work doesn’t show up as a step in the EXPLAIN plan but you can see the “cost” value jump up before the sort step.  The cost is fine on the step before sort and is large at the start of the sort step.  If I’m correct you should be able to see this work in the STL_DIST catalog table for this query.

To fix this you will need to analyze your tables to see how you can reduced this “row creation” or change the query to create the result without the DISTINCT.

All this is best guess so to your questions.

1. The order by is taking some time but it is not the main issue.  The difference between start and end cost is not that great.
2. The EXPLAIN plan cost is just Redshift’s best guess as to how expensive each step will be.  The 2 cost values are the begin and end cost estimates.  There isn’t an exact definition for the cost value but it is a metric that Redshift uses to evaluate relative cost of steps for the query plan to be optimized.  You will want to look at the query actual execution information to really see what is happening.
3. The join style is fine.  That just means that Redshift is using the distribution ALL to optimized the join.  No data needs to move around the cluster for this join to happen because it is using the “local” copy of the TE table.  The issue is coming up on the aggregation step when the result of the join needs to get organized and redistributed around the cluster.
4. As mentioned above the generated sub query is Redshift trying to manage the data for a very large query.  This is the basis for my assessment that the JOIN is making a lot of data.

If it was me I’d just run a test query on the output of the JOIN with the WHERE clause and count the number of rows produced.  This will tell you ow big the data is that is generated by the JOIN.

(PS. FYI I’m traveling so my ability to reply will be limited for a while.)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to guide me while you are travelling. I removed DISTINCT which removed [XN HashAggregate  (cost=944620.71..944621.21) & XN Subquery Scan volt_dt_0  (cost=944506.75..944606.47)] from explain plan. This improved a bit of performance but every run shows different execution time, query takes 50 seconds, 40 seconds and sometimes it takes 11 seconds. 

I have added additional WHERE clause to reduce the number of records read from a total of 15 million which has improved a bit of performance.

Your message has helped me to learn about explain plan. Thnx.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped.  The fast runs may be due to cached results or source tables.  There’s an option to turn off caching for performance characterization.

Comment: Hi @Bill Weiner, I found the cause for query running for ~40s. It basically gets stuck in the queue, so the query completion time fluctuates and it a bit on the higher side. Do you have any inputs on how to take benchmark of an query please? Thank you.

Comment: You say it "gets stuck in the queue".  Is this the issue you want to address or is this just the explanation for the variability and not where you want to focus?  As for profile the query execution I'd suggest you look at the "actual execution" report in the Redshift console.  This give info on which steps took the most time and if there is skew in the query execution.  I also like to look at the scan, distribution, and spill information in the catalog tables but start with the actual execution report.

Comment: Hi @Bill Weiner, Thank you for the information. And yes I just wanted to add the explanation for the variability that my query gets stuck in the queue which causes the delay sometimes. Thank you